# iframe in php WordPress theme options

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe

We added a new tab in our theme options that loads an iframe.

But due to some reason, I'm not sure why its not loading my page!

```
$options[] = array( "name" => "Theme Update",
                    "type" => "heading");
ob_start();
echo '<iframe src="http://domain.com/updates" width="100%" height="700"></iframe>';
//echo 'Welcome';
$updates_content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
//echo $updates_content;
$options[] = array( "name" => "Updates",
                    "desc" => "",
                    "std" => $updates_content,
                    "type" => "info");
```

Instead of loading my page its sayings "Updates"

Is there anything wrong with the codes? Please Help!

Comment: is there by any chance an extra ob_start() somewhere in the code before this snippet?